# Eclipse/Junit/Tomcat8/dbcp2 AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, apache-commons-dbcp

I am getting the following error when trying to run my JUNIT tests from Eclipse. If I deploy my application and add OJDBC7.jar to the Tomcat 8 Lib i have no problems.

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.isValid(I)Z
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:914)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:283)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2304)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2287)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.use42Api(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:85)
at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:63)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 40 more
```

I have added the following to the projects pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And added the Jar to my repository using `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar`

As I say this issue is only in eclipse.

Test-Context:

```
    <bean id="spDatasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What happens if you run `mvn test` on the command line, outside Eclipse?

Comment: The same occurs when running the tests using 'mvn test'....

Comment: Ok, it sounds to me like maybe something somewhere got corrupted. It works fine in Tomcat but not in Maven, and they are using physically different JAR files. I would suggest you re-download the ojdbc7.jar and re-install it into your maven repository. Or you can test this hypothesis first by copying the maven copy of the JAR from your local repo into Tomcat and seeing if it works or not.